# how to make text change when you hover over it without it twitching?

Tags: css, hover, pseudo-element, css-content

As I understand it, CSS can be used to change the content of an element on `:hover` in a basic way. I am using this code

HTML:

```
<button><span>3 replies</span></button>
```

CSS:

```css
button {width:6em}
button:hover span {display:none}
button:hover:before {content:"Reply!"}
```

but when I hover over the button, it twitches very badly

I want mine to be smooth like the music player at [this link](http://www.musiccentro.com/centroadmin/index.php/beats/ws/?beat_id=159)

When you hover over one of the buttons under `lease`, `premium`, or `trackout` price, they switch over to the `+add` text

here is part of my player http://djwckd.com/test

Comment: Your link doesn't seem to twitch for me, and neither does this: http://jsfiddle.net/ExplosionPIlls/zUDmc/

Comment: The link was an example of what he wants

Answer (score 2):

The important thing is to make sure that your layout does not change on hover. The easiest way to achieve this would be to allocate some space in your layout for all of the parts even when not hovering. I'm not sure what sort of layout you are trying to achieve but here is an example:

```
button { width: 6em }
button:hover span {display:none}
button:before { width: 100px; content: ""; }
button:hover:before {content: "Reply!"}
```

By giving the `:before` pseudo-element a size even when it's not hovered the layout shouldn't change when the content changes. You may need to adjust this for the specific layout you want but the general principle is to make sure all of the size-related properties are specified *without* `:hover` and then only adjust non-layout properties (that is, properties that don't affect any box sizes) in the `:hover` state.

Comment: http://djwckd.com/test is part of my player can you see if you can make it do the smooth text change hover

Answer (score 0):

As you provided the link is hovering the background images but in your test link you have given background images before to `<a>` elements, if you want exactly same as link use `background-image: url('image1');` to `a` and `background-image: url('image2');` to `a:hover`.

You can still use positioning the background-images, for this you should have like this.

```
+--------------+
|              |    position this background to a
+--------------+
|    + Add     |    position this background to a:hover
+--------------+
```

Ok! for this make your background 64px width and 32 px height.
then position your background to 
`a{background-image: url('image') left top no-repeat; background-position: 0% 100%;}`

now position your background to

```
a:hover{background-position: 0% 0%;}
```

Comment: im not using images for the buttons im using css buttons

Comment: how do i edit my current code? where do i place the a:hover class and what image do i use if i am using css buttons?

Comment: <button><span><a href="#">3 replies</a></span></button>

Answer (score 0):

I think I have a solution. The trick was one main thing: setting the width of the text's container. I also used onmouseenter instead of onmouseover for faster text change (my theory that onmouseenter is faster then onmouseover). Here is an example:

```js
var videoplayer = {
    text: "<b>Hello World</b>",
    author: "(you)"
  }
```

```html
<div onmouseenter="this.innerHTML = videoplayer.text;" onmouseleave="this.innerHTML = '<b>(hover over me)</b>';" style="background-color: red; padding: 10px; width: 110px; text-align: center; color: white;">(hover over me)</div>
```

Just make sure you set the div's width to the width you need. (If you don't want a background, just change the part that says background-color: red to background-color: transparent). One more thing: you have to use a div or other container with display:block set as its default. I suggest using div. Hope this helps!